# Is there any specific symbol or color for 'Talent'?

Tags: color, logo, symbols

I'm designing a logo which is somehow related to **Talent**. What symbols or colors can (or are good to) represent Talent?

By talent, I mean a natural ability to do something well. I already have something like **a bean** in my mind and I saw **star, medals and young boys/girls** symbols. I just want to know other symbols.

Comment: Prince is talented. And he likes purple. So my answer is: Purple.

Comment: Well the chinese sorted this a while ago. They have a pictogram for talent use that. Anyway if you think chineese is complicated youve hit the catch 13. Making a pictogram or horror a logogram for everything is a bit convoluted. Personally i like the way mayans solved this.

Comment: @joojaa Can you help me to find symbols you mentioned? I didn't found them.

Answer (score 2):

- Gold/silver/bronze medals.
- Blue ribbon (other colors for lesser talent), see
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_ribbon.
- Trophy statuette.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of Blue Ribbon in such context?

Comment: Blue ribbon examples include awards won at art shows and farm fairs.  See the wiki page link that I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Talent > Victory > Winning > Medals > Stars > Rating > Multiple Stars Symbolizing a rating system. > Gold > Laurel Wreath > Olympic Games >

Comment: Thanks. So, you've made a connection between this items?

Answer (score 1):

The greek goddess Athena, because she was born from Zeus's forehead – fully grown and armored.

Comment: Do you have anything to support this idea?

Comment: This seems not only culturally dependant, but also associative thinking taken a little too far. If I _actually_ managed to identify Athena in a tiny symbol (which is wildly unlikely), her scope is immense. She is the goddess of: wisdom, courage, inspiration, civilization, law and justice, just warfare, mathematics, strength, strategy, the arts, crafts, and skill.

Comment: Why the downvote? This a subjective question.

Comment: The downvote is likely because someone disagrees with your answer. It is indeed a subjective question, but users have the ability to judge whether or not your suggestion would be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, but as @RandomO'Reilly said, I think it's culturally dependant.

Comment: @JohnB, but downvotes are relevant to the scoring system for users on Stack Exchange. Considering this question is subjective and probably shouldn't be on here (as fun as a question like this it), a downvote simply amounts to trolling.

Comment: There are no rules enforced for the reasoning or logic behind an individuals votes. Someone down-voting your answer does not come anywhere close to "simply amounting to trolling". That's an extreme misuse of the term. If someone down-votes your answer and doesn't leave a comment, that is their prerogative. If you don't want to consider the feedback you have been offered to improve your answer, that's yours.

Comment: It does amount to trolling if opinion-based questions aren't allowed. The question is irrelevant thus the answer is irrelevant, and it shouldn't count against scoring.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search on talent, returns light-bulb metaphors on their own or placed inside a silhouette of the human head. I haven't suggested a graduation cap in case it singled out users w/o further education qualifications.

However I think you wouldn't go far wrong if you used a star. Like [Britain's got talent](http://www.itv.com/britainsgottalent) or more iconic, [the Hollywood Stars](http://www.shutterstock.com/s/hollywood+star/search.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think light-bulb would be more related to mind and ideas rather than talent. Actually I wanted to use a star, but I think that's been used too much. :)